# Set geom_vline line types and sizes with aes mapping in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics, geom-vline

I'm trying to create a histogram with vertical lines overlaid on top of it. One of the vertical lines shows a target, the rest show percentiles. I would like the line representing the target to be different than the other lines.

I have the data for the lines in a dataframe:

```
lines
   qntls        lbs heights    lts lsz
1  29.00      p5=29 32.2400 dashed 0.1
2  45.25     p25=45 33.5296 dashed 0.1
3  79.00     p50=79 30.9504 dashed 0.1
4 128.00    p75=128 32.2400 dashed 0.1
5 249.25    p95=249 33.5296 dashed 0.1
6 120.00 Target=120 30.9504  solid 0.2
```

I then use the *lines* dataframe to create the geom_vline and geom_label objects:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(
    data = h,
    mapping = aes(
      x = DAYSTODECISION
    ),
    breaks = brks,
    color = clr,
    fill = f
  ) +
  geom_vline(
    data = lines,
    mapping = aes(
      xintercept = qntls,
      color = lbs,
      linetype = lts,
      size = lsz
    ),
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_label(
    data = lines,
    mapping = aes(
      x = qntls,
      y = heights,
      label = lbs,
      hjust = 0 # Label starts on line and extends right
    )
  ) +
  ggtitle(title) +
  labs(
    x = xlab,
    y = ylab
  ) +
  theme_classic()
```

I get this result:

[image]

I want the line for the target to be solid and all other lines to be dashed. For some reason this is reversed in the chart compared to the *lines* dataframe. Additionally, I would expect the target line to be twice as thick as the other lines, but this is not the case.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  # your plot code ... +
  scale_linetype_identity() +
  scale_size_identity()
```

It's unusual in a `ggplot` to put the actual colors/sizes/linetypes you want in the data frame (instead of meaningful labels you might want on a legend, like you do for `lbs`), but if you do the `identity` scales are your friend.

A more standard approach would have your data set up perhaps like this:

```
   qntls        lbs heights is_target 
1  29.00      p5=29 32.2400        no
2  45.25     p25=45 33.5296        no
3  79.00     p50=79 30.9504        no
4 128.00    p75=128 32.2400        no
5 249.25    p95=249 33.5296        no
6 120.00 Target=120 30.9504       yes
```

Then map `linetype = is_target, size = is_target` inside `aes()`, and use manual scales like this:

```
... + 
scale_size_manual(values = c("no" = 0.1, "yes" = 0.2)) +
scale_linetype_manual(values = c("no" = "dashed", "yes" = "solid"))
```

This set-up makes it easy to adjust your graph without changing your data.